# Sort nested dictionary by value in JS

Tags: javascript, dictionary

Can someone please help to figure out the way to sort a dictionary with another dictionary inside in JavaScript?
This is how my dict looks like:

`{'POS2': {'stegano': 0, 'sum': 200, 'misc': 100, 'web': 0, 'ppc': 0, 'crypto': 0, 'admin': 0, 'vuln': 0, 'forensics': 0, 'hardware': 0, 'reverse': 0, 'recon': 100}, ...}`

I want to sort it by 'sum' key that is stored in nested dict.
I can find some solutions written in python, but the challenge here is to achieve the same functionality in JS.
Would appreciate any help.

Comment: You would then expect an array as output, yes?

Comment: Objects are unordered sets of properties. So when you speak of `sort` what output do you expect?

Comment: Thank you, both , for your interest. At first I thought of having dictionary as an output, but having the elements inside reorganized, so the first element would have the smallest sum number. But now that @trincot has mentioned and I did my checking, I can see why that wouldn’t work. My dictionary is an object in JS, which properties are unordered. So, I suppose having an array as an output is the way to go

Answer (score 2):

Just retrieve the inner object using `Object.values` and then use `Array.sort` to sort by it's content. Note that you cannot sort an objects properties as they are per default an unsorted set (or at least, it's not properly described how properties should be sorted on an object)

```js
const dict = {
  'POS2': {
    'stegano': 0, 
    'sum': 200, 
    'misc': 100, 
    'web': 0, 
    'ppc': 0, 
    'crypto': 0, 
    'admin': 0, 
    'vuln': 0, 
    'forensics': 0, 
    'hardware': 0, 
    'reverse': 0, 
    'recon': 100
  }, 
  'POS1': {
    'sum': 100
  },
  'POS3': {
    'sum': 250
  }
};

function orderBySubKey( input, key ) {
  return Object.values( input ).map( value => value ).sort( (a, b) => a[key] - b[key] );
}

console.log( orderBySubKey( dict, 'sum' ) );
```

This sample would remove the outer properties, if you want to keep these, you can change your ordering a bit, for example like

```js
const dict = {
  'POS2': {
    'stegano': 0, 
    'sum': 200, 
    'misc': 100, 
    'web': 0, 
    'ppc': 0, 
    'crypto': 0, 
    'admin': 0, 
    'vuln': 0, 
    'forensics': 0, 
    'hardware': 0, 
    'reverse': 0, 
    'recon': 100
  }, 
  'POS1': {
    'sum': 100
  },
  'POS3': {
    'sum': 250
  }
};

function orderBySubKey( input, key ) {
  return Object.keys( input ).map( key => ({ key, value: input[key] }) ).sort( (a, b) => a.value[key] - b.value[key] );
}

console.log( orderBySubKey( dict, 'sum' ) );
```

Which gives you a different output, but would still allow you to lookup inside the original dictionary

Answer (score 0):

For example, you have next array (similar to your array, but has less properties to readable):

```
let obj = {
    pos1: { sum: 100, name: 'p1' },
    pos2: { sum: 1, name: 'p2' },
    pos3: { sum: 50, name: 'p3' }
};

var result = Object.keys(obj)
    .map(key => { return {key, val: obj[key]}}) // output: unsorted array
    .sort((a, b) => a.val.sum > b.val.sum); 

console.log(result);
```

and as result you will see:

```
[ { key: 'pos2', val: { sum: 1, name: 'p2' } },
  { key: 'pos3', val: { sum: 50, name: 'p3' } },
  { key: 'pos1', val: { sum: 100, name: 'p1' } } ]
```

Comment: And what if the OP wanted to keep the key names like `POS2`?

Comment: @Andy yes, you right. i missed that input parameter is object, not array. I fixed my answer

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't order objects by property you'd need to [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the objects to an array and then sort that. And you'd probably not want to lose the key for each nested object (like POS2), so you'd want to embed that key in the object for safe-keeping.

```js
const obj = {"POS2":{"stegano":0,"sum":2200,"misc":100,"web":0,"ppc":0,"crypto":0,"admin":0,"vuln":0,"forensics":0,"hardware":0,"reverse":0,"recon":100},"POS3":{"stegano":0,"sum":1200,"misc":100,"web":0,"ppc":0,"crypto":0,"admin":0,"vuln":0,"forensics":0,"hardware":0,"reverse":0,"recon":100},"POS4":{"stegano":0,"sum":22,"misc":100,"web":0,"ppc":0,"crypto":0,"admin":0,"vuln":0,"forensics":0,"hardware":0,"reverse":0,"recon":100},"POS5":{"stegano":0,"sum":2001,"misc":100,"web":0,"ppc":0,"crypto":0,"admin":0,"vuln":0,"forensics":0,"hardware":0,"reverse":0,"recon":100}}

// map over the object keys
const out = Object.keys(obj).map(key => {

  // on each iteration return the object with its new key property
  return { ...obj[key], key }

// then sort the array of object by their sums
}).sort((a, b) => a.sum - b.sum);

console.log(out);
```