# Sort nested dict in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I have a Javascript question.

```
var choices = {
    "red": {
        number: 1
    },
    "blue": {
        number: 2
    },
    "black": {
        number: 3
    },
    "green": {
        number: 4
    },
    "white": {
        number: 3
    }
```

How can we get the 2 keys of the dict "choices" with the least "number" ?

In this example it would be "red" and "blue". If there is a tie, I would like to have a random one between the tied one.

All my solutions are really ugly so I am asking for help.

Comment: You should look into [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

Comment: check [this ans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53248638/sort-nested-dictionary-by-value-in-js)

Comment: `Object.keys(choices).sort((a,b) => choices[a].number - choices[b].number).slice(0,2)`